# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el SSID de la conexión activa en C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una app en WinForms y quiero que salga las barritas de red (con un INT me basta) y como es el SSID de la conexión, por ejemplo: VegaFibra_2***6 (el de mi casa) o Redmi Note 9 (zona wifi), he intentado con:

```
NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterface in networkInterfaces)
            {
                if (networkInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Network Interface Name: " + networkInterface.Name);
                    MessageBox.Show("Network Interface Description: " + networkInterface.Description);
                    MessageBox.Show("Network Interface Type: " + networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType);
                    MessageBox.Show("Is connected? " + networkInterface.OperationalStatus);

                    if (networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
                    {
                        IPInterfaceProperties ipProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();
                        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ipProperties.UnicastAddresses)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("IP Address: " + ip.Address.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("----------------------------------------");
                }
            }
```

Pero me sale esto:
MessageBox.Show("Network Interface Name: " + networkInterface.Name): (wifi)

MessageBox.Show("Network Interface Description: " + networkInterface.Description): Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168

MessageBox.Show("Network Interface Type: " + networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType): (Wireless80*1 *)

MessageBox.Show("Is connected? " + networkInterface.OperationalStatus): (up)

MessageBox.Show("IP Address: " + ip.Address.ToString()): ***********************************

MessageBox.Show("IP Address: " + ip.Address.ToString()): ***************